# htaccess and 301 redirects - multiple domains

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, multiple-domains

I have the following which redirects `mydomain1.co.uk` and `mydomain1.com` to `www.mydomain1.com` perfectly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.mydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to add an additional rule for a second domain, that will redirect all non www traffic for `mydomain2.com` to `www.mydomain2.com`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You seems to have quite a few domains and subdomains pointing to the same folder (so they share the same .htaccess) which makes your original approach not suitable for such situation. Use these rules instead of yours:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain1.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These rules will only work with domains/subdomains described in your question and will not catch any other subdomains (e.g. `hello.mydomain1.com` will not trigger these rules).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would have been to check for `mydomain1` in the hostname *and* is not `www.mydomain1.com` (the canonical hostname) then redirect to the canonical hostname.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain1\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This handles any number of variations of `mydomain1` (assuming `mydomain1` could not legitimately occur as part of `mydomain2`) and FQDN that end in a dot. Then repeat for `mydomain2`.

If both domains have the same canonical hostname format (ie. `www.example.com`, as in your example) then you could combine these two (or more) rules into one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (mydomain1|mydomain2) [NC]
RewriteCond %1@@%{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z]+)@@www\.\1\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `\1` in the second *CondPattern* is an internal backreference to the domain name matched in the first *condition*. `%1` is a backreference to the last **matched** *CondPattern* (ie. the domain name in the first *CondPattern*). The second *condition* is never "matched" since it is a *negated* pattern.